# Validating errors with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, bdd

So I've got the following method, which is expected to load a file.

```
class Loader
    def load_file(file_to_load)  
        if not FileTest.exists?(file_to_load)
          raise "File Does Not Exist"
        end
    end
end
```

I am using Cucumber to validate this works and I'm using the following step definitions:

```
Given an import file doesn't exist
When a user runs the loader
Then the import fails
```

The step definition for the 'When' steps looks like this:

```
When /^a user runs the loaderd$/ do
   @loader = MovieLoader.new
   @loader.load_file
end

Then /^the import fails%/

end
```

However, I since the exception is raised as part of the load_file method call in the When step, how do I validate it in the 'Then' step.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

in the when step capture the error and validate the error exists in the then step.

I don't do ruby, so i don't know the syntax but basically you want something like this in pseudo code:

```
When /^a user runs the loaderd$/ do
   @loader = MovieLoader.new
   try
      @loader.load_file
   catch
      error = "load failed"
end

Then /^the import fails%/
    if (error != "load failed")
        raise "expected error was not raised"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Put @loader.load_file in the then step.

Comment: In this case logic of the steps will be lost.

Comment: @p0deje - i'd rather give a different solution more than downgrade

Comment: If I had one, I'd definitely gave. That's why I +1 question (it's rather complicated case) and -1 your answer (it doesn't solve it)

Comment: Thanks guys.   I'd imagine that validating the fact that an error is not an outrageous thing to do and it should be doable without having to rearrange the logic of the steps.

Comment: Why not use @loader.load_file.should_raise "File Does Not Exist" in the then step?

Comment: That implies I can't have a 'When' step that says '@loader.load_file', correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. 
And if I've answered correctly your question please up-vote :-) I don't like to have that -1 there...